# cogito.adminSetUserPassword is not a function in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

When i'm trying to use cognito.adminSetUserPassword in aws lambda the console says: cognito.adminSetUserPassword is not a function but when i'm trying in localhost its works fine. The current code is the follow y nodejs with express.

```
module.exports.set_password = async (req, res) => { 
  try {
   const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
   });

   const { id: Username } = req.params;
   const newPassword = 'newPassword@12333'

   await cognito.adminSetUserPassword({
    UserPoolId: process.env.USERPOOL_ID,
    Username,
    Password: newPassword,
    Permanent: false,
   }).promise();

  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
     res.status(error.code).json({
      code: error.code,
      message: error.message,
     });
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you please edit your Question to show the code that is causing the problem and please include the _exact_ error message.

Comment: The code is the shown above. Only works in localhost but when I deploy it doesn't work in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python language for your lambda code then boto3 is the sdk which provides you access to other aws services. And boto3 has CognitoIdentityProvider which definitely has adminSetUserPassword function

Official Documentation : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_set_user_password

Comment: Then you can use this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminSetUserPassword-property

Answer (score 0):

If your lambda function is nodejs, then set below stuff in your package.json and that will enable the required.

- "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^4.5.7",
- "aws-sdk": "^2.828.0",